# Can't load URL into iframe with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, controller

Using AngularJS, Im trying to load the "myLink" URL address to iframe in another html.
data.No is the id that i pull from another place and works fine (get the Id that i need for the url)

in the controller - "TransactionsCtrl":

```
$scope.myLink = "http://"the real url"+ data.No +"&file="+ data.No +"&contract_id="+ data.No;
console.log($scope.myLink);
```

in the HTML :

```
<div ng-controller= "TransactionsCtrl">
    <iframe ng-src="{{myLink}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

and all i get is this :

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{myLink}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL
```

when i hard coded the url its working fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the controller you should use:

```
   $scope.myLink =  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(myUrl)
```

Comment: This is good if you have one url or a set of urls.. not so good if you need to pass them in dynamically as you have to set them in the controller as opposed to being passed as a var. While this is correct. The answer below from saghar.fadaei is the solution to use.

Answer (score 9):

It works for me : you can write this in js code as a function

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
  return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
}
$scope.iframe = {src:"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lx7ycjC8qjE"};
```

and use it in your view :

```
 <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(iframe.src)}}"></iframe>
```

or you can write it as a filter like :

```
.filter('trusted', function($sce){
return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
};
```

})

and use it in view :

```
 <iframe ng-src="{{iframe.src | trusted}}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

url: string = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ';
urlSafe: SafeResourceUrl;

constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

this.urlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).