# How to write a $state parameter into an view (ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have this scenario an user clicks on a link, I catch the event and prevent it from redirect me to this url, instead I save it and send the user to an specific state/view using `$state.go('app.myState', {myParam: url_captured});`

The parameter gets sended but now I need to show this url inside an iframe in the view, I tried

```
<iframe src="{{$state.params.myParam}}"></iframe>
```

but it doesn't show anything just throw an empty iframe.

How to I access the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use this:

```
src="{{$state.params.myParam}}"
```

involve that in the scope of this controller there's a var named `$state`

add this to your controller:

```
$scope.myParam = $state.params.myParam
```

then replace the iframe with:

```
<iframe src="{{myParam}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: It worked in the way that the param pass, but then I got this error `ionic.bundle.js:21162 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{myParam}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://wikipedia.org` The weird thing is if I write the iframe src directly I get no errors.

Comment: this is another problem. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990014/cant-load-url-into-iframe-with-angularjs) and use `$sce`